# Reading Stream after using enableReceiveTimeout

Tags: java, gps, readline

I am currently working on a Java project, one of the aims of which is to display current position of the user on a map. After code completion, I realized that there is a possibility of the user unplugging the GPS device while the application is still running. On recreating the above scenario, I found that the application forever hangs at the code :

```
detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine();
```

So, I went to the good old Java Docs and found the method **enableReceiveTimeout()** and everything works perfect. *(Value is 30000, 30 seconds)*

Now, I have managed to think of another scenario, wherein the user may re-plug the device back on. In this scenario, my clientele would want the device to start reading again. But unfortunately that ain't happening.

I am working with my buddy "The Good Old Java Docs" and would love for any one of you geek gods to guide me on my journey.

My Code :

```
try {
    myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPort.enableReceiveTimeout(3000);

    if(myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine() != null)
    {   
        myGPSConnector.nmeaResponse = myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(myGPSConnector.nmeaResponse);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    locationString = "GPS Device not detected.";
}
```

@derrabink : It can be a different stream, cuz I tried to work with the following extension to my code :

```
try {
    myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPort.enableReceiveTimeout(3000);

    if(myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine() != null)
    {   
        myGPSConnector.nmeaResponse = myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(defaultGPSConnector.nmeaResponse);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    locationString = "GPS Device not detected.";

    try {
        defaultGPSConnector.detectedGPSPort.enableReceiveTimeout(30);
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e1) 
        {
            System.out.println("UnsupportedCommOperationException");
                        }

    try {
            locationString = defaultGPSConnector.detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine();
        }
    catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            System.out.println("IOException ");
        }
```

And It always prints **IOException**

Comment: Can it be that after reconnecting there will be a different stream? If so, you might want to start probing the reconnected device's stream every so often (until success), once readLine() takes a little while.

Comment: Also, are you sure that your two readLine() statements are correct the way they are? Looks to me that you're doing two reads, and only keeping the result of the second one.

Comment: Works perfectly fine my lord...

Answer (score 1):

I'd change your `if` for a `while` statement:

```
while ( myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine() == null ) {
    // don't do anything. Will stay here until the client decides to plug it again.
}

myGPSConnector.nmeaResponse = myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine();
System.out.println(myGPSConnector.nmeaResponse);
```

Edit.

```
for (long stop=System.nanoTime()+TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(30); stop>System.nanoTime();)
{

    //this loop will execute for exactly 30 seconds
    if ( myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine() != null ) 
    {
        myGPSConnector.nmeaResponse = myGPSConnector.
        detectedGPSPortBufferReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(myGPSConnector.nmeaResponse);
    }
}
```

So, you have a loop for 30 seconds, if nothing if there's nothing to read during those, that means the guy has better things to do than playing with GPS.

This is my approach. Caution, may not work.

Comment: That is a very good Idea Sire . But thou seem to neglect the scenario wherein my clientele shall not want to re-pug the device.

So, basically it goes like this:

**Unplug >> Wait for 30 seconds >> If pluged within 30 seconds =  Continue else exit**

Comment: so he wants to start reading again after unplug-->30 seconds--> not plugged again?

Comment: there is a possibility, Yes. But he has too make up his mind within 30 seconds. Else, the app will exit.

Comment: take a look, it may help you. if not, please tell me so I punish them for inefficiency.

Comment: It Doesnt work My' Lord ...I am sorry .. but it had to be said.

Comment: hmmmmm!! okay, you could try this instead:   if ( myGPSConnector.detectedGPSPortBufferReader.ready() )  and then read the line, etc.. it MAY work. The ready() function tells you if there's something to read. So, you check if there's something, and then read it.